# Plural von »Stadt« – »Städt« oder »Städte«?

Tags: declension, grammatical-number

Ich lerne Deutsch. Das Lehrbuch, das ich benutze, verwendet den Satz:

> Kleinere Städt lohnen einen Besuch.

Ist *Städt* der richtige Plural von *Stadt?*

Comment: („Die Städte lohnen **sich** einen Besuch” ist dafür besser, oder?)

Comment: @DiN0bot, No, that would be wrong (or at least very poor style).

Comment: Ich schließe diese Frage, da sie anscheinend auf einem Tippfehler basiert.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bis auf wenige Verwendungen innerhalb verschiedener Mundarten ist "Städte" der korrekte Plural. "Städt" scheint also ein Fehler im Buch zu sein.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

[„Stadt“ in canoo.net, Deutsche Wörterbücher und Grammatik](http://canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=Stadt&features=%28Cat%20N%29%28Gender%20F%29&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive)

Comment: It'd be better to add a summary of the link to your answer.

Comment: What does this answer add that the first one didn't already answer with respect to the question?

Comment: fzwo: A source for answering pluralization questions like this in the future. Sorry-- adding comments is a new thing for me which only recently became available (points?).

Answer (score 0):

The plural of `Stadt` is `Städte`. Never ever read or heart `Städt` before.